# Create a txt file in java, and read it out again in java

Tags: java

So I first created an groep of persons by p numbers of objects

```
box1:
public static Person[] createPersons(int p) {

people = new Person[p];
    for(int i=0; i < p; i++) {
        people[i] = new Person("Mr. Persons" + i, 20 + i, 'M');
    }

    menuSelection();
    return people;
}
```

And I wrote it to an text file:

```
box2:
public static void writePersons (Person[] person, String filePerson){

    if (people != null) {

    try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(filePerson)) {

        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);

        os.writeInt(p);
        os.writeObject(people);

        os.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println(p+" Person written successfully to " + filePerson);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing to write.");
    }

    menuSelection();
}
```

So in java it looks like this:

```
box3:
Mr. Person0     20      M
Mr. Person1     21      M
Mr. Person2     22      M
Mr. Person3     23      M
Mr. Person4     24      M
Mr. Person5     25      M
```

But when I open my text file it looks like this:

```
¬í w   ur   [LPerson;4Ýd
—ì-b  xp   sr Person        I ageC genderL namet Ljava/lang/String;xp    Mt 
Mr. Person0sq ~     Mt 
Mr. Person1sq ~     Mt 
Mr. Person2sq ~     Mt 
Mr. Person3sq ~     Mt 
Mr. Person4sq ~     Mt 
Mr. Person5
```

How to read out this textfile again? And put it in the format how it looks like in java (see box3)

Comment: You'll have to read each object in your text file and cast it to a Person object. Tada :)

Comment: Do you only want to read it in Java or do you want to be able to read it with say notepad as well? Because you're using `ObjectOutputStream` and `writeObject` which uses the default serializer.

Comment: I want only want to read it in Java. But I have no idea where to start with my code or something like that. Thanks for your fast answers guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read an object you wrote to a file in Java using `writeObject`, you have to use `readObject` (of `ObjectInputStream`) on the file.

Defer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)) about `ObjectOutputStream`:

> The method writeObject is used to write an object to the stream. Any object, including Strings and arrays, is written with writeObject. Multiple objects or primitives can be written to the stream. The objects must be read back from the corresponding ObjectInputstream with the same types and in the same order as they were written.

So in your case, you'll have to read it something like this:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePerson)) {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    int p = ois.readInt();
    Person[] persons = new Person[p];
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        persons[i] = (Person)ois.readObject();
    }
    ois.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like :

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter ("D:\\test.txt");
printWriter.println (p.getName());
printWriter.print (p.getSex());
printWriter.print (p.getAge());
printWriter.close ();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write Strings instead of Objects,
better to create a toString() method and use accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use ObjectOutStream. That's computer Jargon. You just need PrintWriter.

Comment: Old term... used to be thrown around a lot when I was young. It means only the computer can make sense of it.